# Filtering out rows in a matrix containing only 0 in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have the matrix

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 6), 3)
```

I need to filter out rows where both columns have a value of 0 in effect returning the matrix:

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 3, 4, 6), 3)
```

I have tried

```
m[m[, 1] > 0 & m[, 2] > 0]
```

but this returns a vector instead of a matrix stripped of rows with only 0. This should be simple but I am stuck.

Thanks,
-Elizabeth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you had many columns

```
m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    3    6
m^2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   16
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    9   36
rowSums(m^2)
[1] 17  0 45
m[rowSums(m^2)>0,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    3    6
```

Comment: to the rescue again ! Thank you. Could you please tell me what the ^ does or direct me to a help page? I searched ??^ and ?rowSum but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer, as you can see `^` is element-wise power. And it is rowSum{**s**}

Comment: @Elizabeth, one more thing, for symbols like `^` it is ?'^', also ?'['

Answer (score 6):

You are just missing a "," in your own solution.
Use

```
m[m[,1]>0 & m[,2]>0,]
```

and it will work:

```
> m[m[,1]>0 & m[,2]>0,]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    3    6
```

Comment: You're right! That's probably a sign I should go home for the day :)